# Mismatch between file creation time and current time in Python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, file, time

Why is the file creation time less than the time measured before it is created?

```
import os, time

before_creation = time.time()

with open('my_file', 'w') as f:
    f.write('something')

creation_time = os.stat('my_file').st_ctime

print(before_creation)  # 1545031532.8819697
print(creation_time)    # 1545031532.8798425
print(before_creation < creation_time)  # False
```

**Edit** OS is Linux

Comment: Confirmed on https://pyfiddle.io/ .. funny. Maybe this is a resolution thing ebcause time.time() only updates 50-100 times a second and st_ctime may be "faster" - still curious. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time   and   https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stat.html#stat.ST_CTIME

Comment: @PatrickArtner Could be. I ran this in a loop and about 4 out of 1000 times recorded the expected result

Comment: Added to bug tracker:https://bugs.python.org/issue35522

Answer (score 0):

- Since OS module is from CPython and designed initally for the python
  2.x versions. If you run your code in 2.7 version it returns the same value for before_creation and creation_time. Since, the result is
  limited to 2 decimal places only in 2.x version.  
     `eg., 1545073155.03`
- Also, you have to note that when you do `print(os.stat('my_file'))`  we get 
  `posix.stat_result(st_mode=33204, st_ino=12, st_dev=1792, st_nlink=1,
  st_uid=488, st_gid=487, st_size=0, st_atime=1545073155,
  st_mtime=1545073155, st_ctime=1545073155)`
- And if you do
  `print(os.stat('my_file')[9])` we get `1545073155`
   As far as
  solution, you might have to use the time.time() to get the time after
  creation. 
   Considering this there might be a bug during the
  conversion from int to float of the st_ctime.